# Exporting a javascript array as CSV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony, csv

I have a javascript array which i have to save as CSV in client environment..Is that possible using jquery? I have to make in work in all major browsers too..I'm using symfony2 framework..How can this be done if I can pass this array to the server..Please explain the best possible way to pass array as I'm having a pretty large array of associativ arrays..

Comment: the problem will probably be file system access no matter if you directly try saving from Javascript as CSV or pass the data to the server and return a CSV file to be saved on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the data to the server however you'd like (using `$_POST`, `AJAX`, etc.). Once the data arrives at the server, though, this is how *I* would go about sending the data to a CSV file.

```
$serialized_data = $_POST['some_data_array'];

if($downloadFile) // simple condition
{

    $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w+'); // open up write to memory


    foreach($serialized_data  as $row) // $serialized_data represents what you sent to the server from JS
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    rewind($fp);
    $csvFile = stream_get_contents($fp);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($csvFile));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourFile.csv"');
    exit($csvFile);
}
```